# uniform_int_distribution a(), b(), min(), and max()

Tags: c++, c++11, std

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/params
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/min
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/max

It looks like member function `a()` is equivalent to member function `min()`, and member function `b()` is equivalent to `max()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(5, 10);
    std::cout << "a " << dist.a() << '\n';
    std::cout << "b " << dist.b() << '\n';
    std::cout << "min " << dist.min() << '\n';
    std::cout << "max " << dist.max() << '\n';
}
```

prints

```
a 5
b 10
min 5
max 10
```

When compiled using gcc's standard library. Are these functions really identical, and if so, why are `a()` and `b()` defined?

Comment: Is this true for all the distributions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are these functions really identical

They are identical, because it is reasonable and practical to always assume so. It would be true but pedantic and misleading to say it is not an absolute guarantee.

I only have access to MinGW 4.7.1, which I assume its standard library is the same as GCC one. Inside it, the class template `uniform_int_distribution` has members:

```
  /**
   * @brief Returns the inclusive lower bound of the distribution range.
   */
  result_type
  min() const
  { return this->a(); }

  /**
   * @brief Returns the inclusive upper bound of the distribution range.
   */
  result_type
  max() const
  { return this->b(); }
```

So, after function inlining, (`a` and `min`) and (`b` and `max`) should be tanslated into identical code.

Reading the standard section 26.5.8.2.1, you will find that it (only indirectly) says they should return the same value. As a result, a sane library implementer will make them effectively identical or at least not-so-different.

---

> why are a() and b() defined?

I can only guess. It may be about consistency, but the consistency is in a less formal sense.

Mathematically, a uniform distribution is like this:

```
P(i|a,b) = 1/(b-a+1)
```

And in `uniform_int_distribution`, we have

```
uniform_int_distribution::a()
uniform_int_distribution::b()
```

For Bernoulli distribution and `bernoulli_distribution`:

```
P(i|p) = [complicated]

bernoulli_distribution::p()
```

Poisson:

```
P(i|mean) = [complicated]

poisson_distribution::mean()
```

Normal:

```
P(x|mean, standard-deviation) = [complicated]

normal_distribution::mean()
normal_distribution::stddev()
```

We can observe that they all tell their parameters. It is not useful to generic code, but that may be helpful in some situations.

Comment: Accepted because this answer shows how other distributions have differently-named but similar-in-concept member functions.

Answer (score 2):

Every random number distribution `D` must have methods

```
D::result_type D::min();
D::result_type D::max();
```

which return the "greatest lower bound and the least upper bound on the values potentially returned by `d`’s `operator()`, as determined by the current values of `d`’s parameters" (§25.1.6, `[rand.req.dist]`; quote is from paragraph 3(d); the requirement is in Table 117).

Also, there is an expectation that a distribution `D` and its associated parameter type `D::param_type` (called `P` in the following quote) will have corresponding constructors and parameter accessors. Paragraph 9 of the same section:

> For each of the constructors of `D` taking arguments corresponding to parameters of the distribution, `P` shall have a corresponding constructor subject to the same requirements and taking arguments identical in number, type, and default values. Moreover, for each of the member functions of `D` that return values corresponding to parameters of the distribution, `P` shall have a corresponding member function with the identical name, type, and semantics.

So `std::uniform_int_distribution::min` and `std::uniform_int_distribution::max` are the bounds of a particular distribution instance's possible return values, while `std::uniform_int_distribution::a` and `std::uniform_int_distribution::b` are the parameter values which constructed that particular instance. As it happens, in the particular case of `std::uniform_{int,real}_distribution`, the parameters precisely correspond to the bounds, but the requirements suggest that both bounds and parameters should be provided.

I suppose it would have been possible to also call the parameter accessors `min` and `max`, but the committee chose not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

`a()` and `b()` return distribution parameters while `min()` and `max()` return minimum and maximum potentially generated value. For the uniform distribution the value returned by `min()` and `a()` are equal, and same for `max()` and `b()`. In general, for other distributions there may not be such correspondence, so I guess `a()` and `b()` are there for consistency.

Comment: Aside from `uniform_real_distribution`, it looks like there aren't any other distributions that provide `a()` and `b()` member functions. Do you know any others? So I guess that indeed they were kept for consistency.

Comment: @vsoftco No, I don't. Every distribution has differently named parameters.